# Ionic 2 - Background image sanitizer and CSS property

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an Ionic app which display some cards.
The background of a card is a full picture. I had this style code for styling:

```
style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6), rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6)), url('merl')"
```

But now, I need to change dinamically my picture, so I used:

**home.html**

```
style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6), rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6))" [style.background-image]="getBackground(event.picture)"
```

**home.ts**

```
getBackground (image) {
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${image})`);
}
```

The problem is that my CSS filter is not shown, the picture is displayed without filter.
What can I do to display the CSS filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your filter to `getBackground`

something like

```
getBackground (image) {
  let cssFilter = 'linear-gradient(rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6), rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6))';
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${image}), ${cssFilter}`);
}
```

effectively setting

```
background-image: url(...), linear-gradient(rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6), rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6))
```

your current way would be overriding

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6), rgba(31, 37, 51, 0.6))
```

with

```
background-image: url(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. ${cssFilter} must be placed before ${image} in order to work. Great solution, thanks a lot!